# Problems Shortcut JNLP

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a problem with JNLP.

When a computer has two Java versions installed, 64 and 32 bits. The computer executes the version 32 bits by default.

And the shortcut is

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\javaws.exe -localfile 
    "C:\Users\Micro\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\43\b9706ab-6de97627"
```

How do I force the shortcut execute by `C:/Windows/System32/javaws.exe` independent the version of Java?

Comment: Can´t we just change the shortcut replacing C:\Windows\SysWOW64 by C:/Windows/System32 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The computer executes the version 32 bits by default.

Not exactly. It rather depends on the calling application.

Let's see two examples:

1. Start cmd.exe (use WINDOWS+R and type cmd)
2. run "java -version" and you get

   ```
   java version "1.7.0_03"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
   ```
3. Start cmd.exe via 32 bit program (e.g. total commander)
4. run "java -version" and you get

   ```
   java version "1.7.0_03"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b05)
   Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode, sharing)
   ```

As can try to use the stubs in windows\system32 and windows\syswow64 directly. The only change:

- you can downgrade from 64bit to 32 bit using

  ```
  c:\Windows\Syswow64\java -version
  ```

The only way I know to elevate from 32 bit to 64 bit is to run the 64bit version explicitely using

```
    "c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -version
```

This logic also applies to all other java commands using wrappers in windows\system, like javaws.

=> link to "c:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaws.exe"